# Problem when I try to update database information - DOESN'T UPDATE Just create a new row

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am creating a table. I conneced it with database. It is receving information. Also I create a form where I can add new data and it is working. Also I can access each row if the table in a separate file. now I am trying make an edit button to edit information from a row.
So, when I press EDIT button is open a new page and retrive all information into a form where I can chage the data. The problem is when I press SUBMIT button -> it is going to home page and create a new row in database just with id.
I will post some screenshots and code, maybe somebody can help me

here you have a link to my website to make you undestand better.
https://www.bogdanho.com/majorProject/index.php?page=default

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
<!-- container -->
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="page-header">
      <h1>Update Shop Details</h1>
  </div>

  <?php
// get passed parameter value, in this case, the record ID
// isset() is a PHP function used to verify if a value is there or not
$shop_id=isset($_GET['shop_id']) ? $_GET['shop_id'] : die('ERROR: Record ID not found.');
 
// read current record's data
try {
    // prepare select query
    $query = "SELECT shop_id, shop_name, shop_phone_number, shop_email, shop_address_no, shop_address_street, shop_town, shop_county, shop_postcode, shop_address_country FROM shop WHERE shop_id = ? LIMIT 0,1";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare( $query );
     
    // this is the first question mark
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $shop_id);
     
    // execute our query
    $stmt->execute();
     
    // store retrieved row to a variable
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     
    // values to fill up our form
    $shop_id = $row['shop_id'];
    $shop_name = $row['shop_name'];
    $shop_phone_number = $row['shop_phone_number'];
    $shop_email = $row['shop_email'];
    $shop_address_no = $row['shop_address_no'];
    $shop_address_street = $row['shop_address_street'];
    $shop_town = $row['shop_town'];
    $shop_county = $row['shop_county'];
    $shop_postcode = $row['shop_postcode'];
    $shop_address_country = $row['shop_address_country'];
}
 
// show error
catch(PDOException $exception){
    die('ERROR: ' . $exception->getMessage());
}
?>

<?php
 
 // check if form was submitted
 if($_POST){
      
    try{
      
        // write update query
        // in this case, it seemed like we have so many fields to pass and 
        // it is better to label them and not use question marks
        $query = "UPDATE shop SET shop_id=:shop_id, shop_name=:shop_name, shop_phone_number=:shop_phone_number, shop_email=:shop_email, shop_address_no=:shop_address_no, shop_address_street=:shop_address_street,shop_town=:shop_town, shop_county=:shop_county,shop_postcode=:shop_postcode, shop_address_country=:shop_address_country WHERE shop_id=:shop_id";
  
        // prepare query for excecution
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        var_dump($conn);
        // posted values
        // $shop_id=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['shopID']));
        $shop_name=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['shopName']));
        $shop_phone_number=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['shopPhone']));
        $shop_email=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['shopEmail']));
        $shop_address_no=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['shopAddressNumber']));
        $shop_address_street=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['shopStreet']));
        $shop_town=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['shopTown']));
        $shop_county=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['shopCounty']));
        $shop_postcode=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['shopPostCode']));
        $shop_address_country=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['shopCountry']));
  
        // bind the parameters
        
        $stmt->bindParam(':shop_name', $shop_name);
        $stmt->bindParam(':shop_phone_number' , $shop_phone_number);
        $stmt->bindParam(':shop_email' , $shop_email);
        $stmt->bindParam(':shop_address_no' , $shop_address_no);
        $stmt->bindParam(':shop_address_street' , $shop_address_street);
        $stmt->bindParam(':shop_town' , $shop_town);
        $stmt->bindParam(':shop_county' , $shop_county);
        $stmt->bindParam(':shop_postcode' , $shop_postcode);
        $stmt->bindParam(':shop_address_country' , $shop_address_country);
        $stmt->bindParam(':shop_id', $shop_id);
          
        // Execute the query
        if($stmt->execute()){
            echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>Record was updated.</div>";
        }else{
            echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Unable to update record. Please try again.</div>";
         }
          
    }
      
    // show errors
    catch(PDOException $exception){
         die('ERROR: ' . $exception->getMessage());
    }
 }
 ?>
 
<!--we have our html form here where new record information can be updated-->
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "? shop_id={$shop_id}");?>" method="post">
    <table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='shop_name' value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($shop_name, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>" class='form-control' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Phone number:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='shop_phone_number' value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($shop_phone_number, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>" class='form-control' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='shop_email' value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($shop_email, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>" class='form-control' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Address No:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='shop_address_no' value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($shop_address_no, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>" class='form-control' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Address street:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='shop_address_street' value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($shop_address_street, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>" class='form-control' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Town:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='shop_town' value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($shop_town, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>" class='form-control' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>County:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='shop_county' value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($shop_county, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>" class='form-control' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Post Code:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='shop_postcode' value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($shop_postcode, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>" class='form-control' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Country:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='shop_address_country' value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($shop_address_country, ENT_QUOTES);  ?>" class='form-control' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type='submit' value='Save Changes' class='btn btn-primary' />
                <a href='index.php?page=viewShop' class='btn btn-danger'>Back to read products</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
   
</div> <!-- end .container -->
```

Comment: Do you get `Record was updated`? If you comment out `->execute()`, will it still insert new records?

Comment: Why are you doing this? `htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['shopCountry']));` It will damage your data. `htmlspecialchars()` is used only when displaying something in HTML document

Comment: @Justinas I don't get RECORD WAS UPDATED and I commented ->execute() and still add a new row in database

Comment: Hmm, I cannot see any `INSERT` in your code, but that would be needed to create new rows. Are you sure you've posted the right code? Or are your `UPDATE`s maybe just setting every column to `NULL`s/some blank values so that it just looks like new empty rows?

Comment: @Dharman - I am begginer and I am trying my best. I do that to collect data from database and display it in the form field...

Comment: An UPDATE statement can not create new rows. You must be performing an INSERT statement without being aware of it. _“when I press SUBMIT button -> it is going to home page”_ - directly upon submitting the form, you mean? Then check what your form action actually contains, and make sure that is correct.

Comment: In this case your form is probably routed to the wrong php page that creates a new record. An update sql statement will not create a new record under any circumstance.

Comment: 1st what is the logic to update shop_id? Also you use same param shop_id - SET shop_id=:shop_id, ......  WHERE shop_id=:shop_id -> $stmt->bindParam(':shop_id', $shop_id);

Comment: _“I do that to collect data from database and display it in the form field”_ - you are not collecting anything from the database, you are processing the POSTed form parameters there. And then further down, where you actually output those default values for the form fields, you are applying `htmlspecialchars` a second time … this really does not make sense. Insert the data into the database as is, without any such manipulation. If you need to manipulate the data for a specific output context (such as HTML) _later_, then do that at that point.

Comment: @CBroe did you take a look ?

Comment: "UPDATE shop SET shop_id=:shop_id, .... don't try to set new value for shop_id !

Comment: So maybe you are hitting insert endpoint in server? Usually `PUT` is meant for updating item and `POST` for creating. Check your requests

Answer (score 0):

change if condition to be sure values are set:`if(isset($_POST['shopID']))`

because values are empty and you should find why they are empty.